# Blackberry config.xml is different in Worklight build methodologies

Tags: eclipse, ant, blackberry, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm building our BB10 environment in Worklight using two different ways.

1- Through Eclipse IDE:

The config.xml in the native folder which has been generated after building the environment contains all the feature that we need in our project.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="MobileBanking" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" rim:backButton="exit">
    <name>Mobile Bank</name>
    <author email="support@company.com">company</author>
    <description>
       Mobile Bank
    </description>
    <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
    </license>
    <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///store/home" />
    <access subdomains="true" uri="file:///SDCard" />

<!-- start_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->


<access subdomains="true" uri="https://mobile-qa.company.ca" />
  <!-- end_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->

<access subdomains="true" uri="tel://*"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://google.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://maps.googleapis.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://googleapis.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://maps.gstatic.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="http://csi.gstatic.com"/>
<access subdomains="true" uri="https://www.company.com/*" />



<!-- <access subdomains="true" uri="*" /> -->

<icon src="icon.png" />
<rim:splash src="splash-1024x600.png" />
<rim:splash src="splash-600x1024.png" />
<rim:splash src="splash-1280x768.png" />
<rim:splash src="splash-768x1280.png" />
<content src="webresources/skinLoader.html" />
<rim:permissions>
    <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_messages</rim:permit>
    <rim:permit>access_location_services</rim:permit>
</rim:permissions>

<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true"/>
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait"/>
<preference name="ChildBrowser" value="disable"/>
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false"/>
<preference name="WebSecurity" value="enabled" />



 <feature id="blackberry.invoke" name="blackberry.invoke" value="blackberry.invoke" />


 <feature id="blackberry.app" name="blackberry.app" value="blackberry.app" />

<feature id="com.blackberry.utils" name="com.blackberry.utils" />
<feature id="com.blackberry.pim.lib" name="com.blackberry.pim.lib" />
<feature id="Battery" name="Battery" value="Battery" />
<feature id="Camera" name="Camera" value="Camera" />
<feature id="Contacts" name="Contacts" value="Contacts" />
<feature id="Device" name="Device" value="Device" />
<feature id="Accelerometer" name="Accelerometer" value="Accelerometer" />
<feature id="Compass" name="Compass" value="Compass" />
<feature id="Notification" name="Notification" value="Notification" />
<feature id="org.apache.cordova.file" name="File" value="File" />
<feature id="FileTransfer" name="FileTransfer" value="FileTransfer" />
<feature id="Geolocation" name="Geolocation" value="Geolocation" />
<feature id="Media" name="Media" value="Media" />
<feature id="Capture" name="media-capture" value="Capture" />
<feature id="NetworkStatus" name="NetworkStatus" value="NetworkStatus" />
<feature id="SplashScreen" name="SplashScreen" value="SplashScreen" />
<feature id="Vibration" name="Vibration" value="Vibration" />
 </widget>
```

2- When I use Ant Worklight Builder, the generated native folder for BB10 contains the following config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="MobileBank" version="1.0.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:rim="http://www.blackberry.com/ns/widgets" rim:backButton="exit">
    <name>MobileBank</name>
    <author email="support@company.com">company</author>
    <description>
       MobileBanking
    </description>
    <license href="http://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical">
    </license>
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///store/home" />
    <access subdomains="true" origin="file:///SDCard" />

    <!-- start_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->
  <access subdomains="true" origin="https://mobile-qa.company.ca" />
  <!-- end_worklight_host_server do not change this line-->

    <access subdomains="true" origin="*" />
    <icon src="icon.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1024x600.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-600x1024.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-1280x768.png" />
    <rim:splash src="splash-768x1280.png" />
    <content src="webresources/skinLoader.html" />
    <rim:permissions>
        <rim:permit>read_device_identifying_information</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_shared</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>read_geolocation</rim:permit>
        <rim:permit>access_pimdomain_contacts</rim:permit>
    </rim:permissions>
 </widget>
```

All the feature tags disappear using Ant builder.

Worklight Ant task version 6.2.0.01.20150329-1923

WebWorks SDK version 2.2.0.15.

I tried Windows and Mac. got same result.
Thank you.

Comment: Always, always, mention your full version number - including the build number.

Comment: I edited it with your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this blog post: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/03/05/ootb-support-blackberry-webworks-2-2/

I've created an application with the BlackBerry 10 environment two times: using The WebWorks 1.0 SDK and the WebWorks 2.2 SDK. The difference in config.xml is due to the SDK used.

- The Worklight builder will create the first config.xml if your environment variable for WEBWORKS_HOME is pointing to WebWorks 1.0.
- The Worklight builder will create the second config.xml if your environment variable for WEBWORKS_HOME is pointing to WebWorks 2.2.

This means that your Studio and Ant .jar file are not of the same version Worklight.
Get the latest iFix from IBM Fix Central; to get the Ant .jar I believe that you will need to extract the Server installation to get it.

Comment: I will download the latest fix from the central. So, using the latest fix with the current webworks SDK version will solve the issue and will include all the features required?

Comment: The blackberry project structure changed in 2.2. Please read online about it.

Comment: You are right, I noticed the difference with SDK version and how it does affect the config.xml. Thank you.

Comment: Idan, we have an old PMR with number 54286,047,649 where we faced an issue with BB and IBM provided us with eclipse update which resolved our issue. However, How can I get the WL Cli fix for that PMR? , they provided direct FTP URL to get the fix. Appreciate your response.

Comment: Ask them to provide you with the latest CLI for your specific version.

Comment: When I use WL version 6.2.0.01-20141106 with WebWorks SDK 2.2.0.15, I generate the first config.xml (Which what I need). However, once I used the latest WL version available on IBM Fix central "Worklight Ant task version 6.2.0.01.20150509-1700", I got the second config.xml. It doesn't seem that the latest fix contains what I need, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Hussam you should have learned by now that these are not questions for stack overflow, which is a programming website. If you have such issues with the product - open a PMR. We can't help you here.